# Purpose of 'method-name' tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently answered a question in the [memberwiseclone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memberwiseclone) Tag (0 followers, 13 questions). I'm wondering if it's useful to have these 'single-method-name'-tags (the same goes for [gettype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gettype), [gethashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gethashcode) and so on).

In my opinion they add no value to the questions itself and thereby shoudn't be used. Also there are tags that seem to be good enough to describe the 'broader concept' of these methods (e.g. [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clone) or [hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashcode)).

Comment: Related question: [Should tags be created for functions of APIs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360271)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Method name tags are good for searching for uses of the method name, common errors when using them, etc.  Of all of the tags that are occasionally seen as marginal, method name tags are the most useful of the bunch.

Comment: Tags which are *just* the method name, without explicitly specifying the library/framework/etc., are ambiguous, at best. IMO, such tags should be burninated.

Comment: I agree that tags which are `library/framework/etc.-methodName` are the most useful of the "marginal" tags. However, they are still, at best, marginal. Unless a particular method is *very* problematic (i.e. gets lots of questions specifically about that method), I don't see it as beneficial to have a specific tag for each method name. If you're interested in a particular method, then you can search for that method in posts. Even with tags for methods, you'd still have to do so, as you can't be guaranteed that what you're looking for is actually tagged with the method tag.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion, and according to some feedback on the question [Should tags be created for functions of APIs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360271/should-tags-be-created-for-functions-of-apis), such tags shouldn't be created.

Some of the reasons that speak against tags on function level at all can be found in the answer to this question but there is an additional reason for the tags mentioned here: All of them are ambiguous and are used for similar but not identical concepts in multiple languages ([gettype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gettype): C#, Java, C++, php; [gethashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gethashcode): C#, Java, delphi). None of these tags does have any specific meaning without an additional language tag which makes them somehow meta-tags.

If the only reason is to make these questions easier searchable, then they should contain the method name in the title.

Comment: 100% agree. There was a point on the other question that people most likely won't be experts in a single function. IMO it just pollutes the tag ecosystem without contributing anything meaningful.