# Tag with method name

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

I've [asked recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358128/1997232) to burninate [tolist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tolist). According to downvotes and answer to [this not-popular question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260664/1997232) I was wrong because:

> Method name tags are good for searching for uses of the method name, common errors when using them, etc. Of all of the tags that are occasionally seen as marginal, method name tags are the most useful of the bunch.

Then (only as an example!) I see complete [burnination of convert tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355395/1997232), which **could be** potentially be a tag to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye(v=vs.110).aspx) or [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ya4hsah(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

### Question: what should I do with tags which are method names *for real*? Ignore and skip?

Personally I have feeling what methods names are too narrow and specific. If e.g. I'd be looking for `ToArray()` method, then I'd for sure use language tag and maybe several technology tags [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq) and then **rely on plain text somewhere in the message** to search for `"toarray"` (note: not a tag).

Using tags like [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq) [toarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toarray) is an overkill if allowed, as then **every method should have** its tag and since methods can do different thing in different languages - that's very quickly become a mess. Though with language tag it will still lead to a correct destination, but what about description of the tag? Are you going to list all methods from all languages?

### Question: why method names as tags are good? Why those *have to be* tags?

I've looked into [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site

Which say nothing about what tags can be created. And then everybody understand tags differently (at least me), creating job for others. What is meta-tag btw? The link in help, instead of giving formal description, leads to some "blogged" blog, which I have difficulty to understand.

Maybe it is worth adding kind of *guidelines* to help as to which tags are ok to create and which aren't?

Comment: the problem with some tags, like convert, was/is that they are all over the place. It doesn't serve as a signpost to find relevant questions in a single context. The arguments on your tolist burninate request was that they seemed to be used solely in the c# context. It didn't hurt, so it doesn't need to be curated.