# What do to with newly created tags that refer to class names or method titles?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

Recently I've been buzzing around the 10k tools > Stats > New tags section in order to intercept tags in need of curation as they are created. (Examples of what I'm doing: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72824690/revisions), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72810888/revisions)).

It was asked before [What to do about tags for classes and methods?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367730/what-to-do-about-tags-for-classes-and-methods) but that question refers to the curation of established tags, and the answers don't show strong consensus in either direction. Others also asked about [Tag with method name](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358293/tag-with-method-name) without receiving an answer at all.

Tags with class names and method names bother me, *especially if they are new tags*, mainly because either we have:

- super-narrow Java-style names like [springbootservletinitializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/springbootservletinitializer) (this tag exists at the time of writing)
- unspecific tags like [ole-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ole-object) which could be Excel but also .NET and you need to actually go see where the tag is used to figure out which one it is. Depending on who decides to write an excerpt [after the fact](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418253/should-creating-a-tag-require-a-more-refined-process?noredirect=1&lq=1), this also has high potential to be hijacked for one technology only, and then need disambiguation, or just stay ambiguous forever.

When these tags do happen to have established counterparts, [as in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72777165/revisions), or [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72774206/revisions) it's an obvious fix. When they don't have one, what should we do?

Remove it or just leave it be?

Personally, I'm not sold on the idea that these tags add anything meaningful to the post. I don't believe one can be a level 60 warlock in `springbootservletinitializer` without also being one in `spring-boot`. At best it's noise, at worst it's a disambiguation/burnination waiting to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do nothing, unless there's an issue.

Clean-up of such tags later does not become an issue, because they can be dealt with expediently and *en masse*. Since they are on-topic (nearly by definition), and always overlap with another tag (if nothing else, the main language/framework tag), they can always be simply merged into that with a single click by a moderator.

Comment: Super narrow tags perhaps can be easily merged, but what about the unspecific ones that may refer to multiple frameworks? Then a single-click-merge requires disambiguation first

Answer (score 5):

This is how we create issues for the future. We do not need tag for every #hashtag, `keyword` or <reserved word> that programming languages are capable of producing. They create issues by crowding out more relevant tags. It doesn't matter that you tag your question with [springbootservletinitializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/springbootservletinitializer) [springapplicationwebapplicationinitializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/springapplicationwebapplicationinitializer) and [webapplicationinitializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webapplicationinitializer) and not using [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring). Remember, tags are the only thing that connects askers with the people that are able to answer them. People knows how to answer spring questions, not about "SpringApplicationWebApplicationInitializer".

As a general rule, if you need to combine tags with another tags to actually convey useful meaining, just remove it. Creating tags just for the sake of it doesn't work and we already have enough tags as is, many of them on the best of case provide zero value.

Also, the same rules that apply for tag creation, applies for tag stewardship. We already know that very specific tags do not work and are routinelly removed.

Answer (score 5):

It seems it's often the case the tags are just spitballed in hopes that something from it is relevant enough for someone to find it, either in looking to answer a question or in searching for an answer.

In the general sense I'd agree with Cody here. If you've not a lot of context/experience in the tag then leaving it be is the best option as they are typically, eventually dealt with.

If it's the case that the new tag is created and appended to a set of tags that you've what could be considered "subject matter expert" in, then I'd say it could/should be obvious if the newly created tag is relevant and adds anything new over existing tags. If they don't then remove them before they've time to take root and become an issue for later cleanup efforts.

Comment: The essence of this post is: let main-tag-SMEs take care of it; I'm not fully convinced though. We have ample evidence of SMEs who don't understand or don't care how SO works, how can I know there will be anyone at all to curate their own tags? However this answer is consistent with Cody's reactive approach.

Comment: This answer ignores that some tags have exactly zero relevant experts by definition: arrays, internet, hacking, etc. Experts existing should be a requirement for a tag to exist, not a nice to have.

Comment: @blackgreen I don't we think *can* ever assume anyone else on the site knows how to use the site. Best *you* can do is *you*. Yes, I suppose my answer *does* assume some good faith in others curating content, but the point was more about if *you*, as a SME, see bad tags, to handle it now and not allow the "snowball" to start.

Comment: @Braiam How does this answer ignore that some tags have, in your opinion, absolutely zero relevant experts? Or rather, why does that even matter? If *you* see a question with what *you* deem to be irrelevant tags, what expert do you need to wait for to remove it and/or replace with a more relevant tag? If you aren't comfortable making that determination then this falls squarely into the first category: leaving it to be dealt with later by a SME or tag cleanup effort. I don't disagree with you that new tags should be vetted out better, if that's your point?

Comment: @DrewReese because for a general policy it should be widely applicable. See my answer on this question for a widely applicable policy (ie. no tags about X should be created, because Y). This answer implies that every tag has expert, something that is not true. Also implies that any topic deserves a tag, also untrue, and only tries to shift a problem that shouldn't exist around instead of preventing it from ever existing. We shouldn't need to have experts to figure out their tags, they should only create them when they find a question that no other tag applies, like the help center says.

Comment: @Braiam You know, you're absolutely correct. When you figure out how to create a tag generating system that can determine if the user *actually* knows what they are talking about you should sell it to SO make a bunch of money.

Comment: We already have that, it's called "we do not allow users to create tags that have no point to be on the system" and enforce it with humans. We do not need to automate/algorithm every single thing on the site, just have a sane policy, have the tools that allows to apply it consistently and do so.

Comment: @Braiam Sorry, I thought it was obvious that was sarcasm. Curating newly created tags is literally what the OP is asking how to manage, and the answers here explain how to do that. What are you even trying to discuss here? Or do you just have an odd way of agreeing and making it sound like there's an issue to discuss? ‍♂️

Comment: Sadly, sarcasm doesn't work well. Also, I don't know if you've noticed, but people really try to be edgy online and take seriously ridiculous stances, like [throwing wrenches on the tag creation process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404893/792066) which works fine.

Comment: @Braiam So we all seem to understand that there's an issue with how easy it is to create tags, but people trying to suggest improvements to that process are edgy and take seriously ridiculous stances in your opinion? Hmm, interesting.

Comment: No, the process of creating a tag isn't the problem. The problem is the concept of tag itself that people doesn't have clear. There are two orthogonal issues here: tag destruction is stupid hard and there isn't a clear guidance on what topics should have tags. Solving one wouldn't solve the other. Making tag creating harder also wouldn't solve either. We need to have a policy on what kind of things can be tags and SE needs to develop an easy to use tool to assist tag destruction. People trying to trow wrenches into the tag creation process do not help either of those.