# Should tags be created for functions of APIs?

Tags: discussion, tag-creation-process

Today I was on a post for the [dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo) and I saw that the user editing the question also created the [dojo.tojson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo.tojson) which seems an overkill to me as it is part of the dojo framework.

When I pointed it out, the user mentioned that it is for future questions concerning that topic.

I find it strange personally if every second function inside a framework gets a tag created, but I don't seem to find any tag creation guidelines :( (well, except for those most often mentioned on the burniate requests)

The question with the tag can be found here: 
[.map() is not a function Error on Mapping Dynamically created Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662184/map-is-not-a-function-error-on-mapping-dynamically-created-object)

Now, thanks to Martijn, I was pointed to when [tags can be created](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work), but there is not a default guideline for what they should be created.

I didn't feel that the original question was the appropriate place to have the discussion about the tag that got created, so I wanted to ask what is the community view on tag creation and if tags should be created for "common" functions inside an api (as @chsdk mentioned in the comments here, before the edit)

The suggested duplicate for this question was linked as this one
[Purpose of 'method-name' tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260664/purpose-of-method-name-tags)

However, I do believe mine is different from that question in so far that I am asking if tags should be created for specific functions of an api, should it really be that specific, while the suggested duplicate is rather concerning general method names (like memberwiseclone).

Comment: From the [Stackoverflow **Tags** page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) you can see that :  *A tag is a keyword or label that **categorizes your question** with other, similar questions. **Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question**.*

Comment: @chsdk Yeah, that defines what a Tag is, not when they should be created, I cannot imagine that suddenly [tag:HTMLDocument.getElementById], [tag:HTMLDocument.getElementsByClassName], [tag:HTMLDocument.getElementsByTagName], ... would be coming up, I think that would rather lead to mistagging a question by only using the as specific as possible tag

Comment: When you create a new tag, it's only a suggestion, until it's peer reveiewed by moderators, so if that tag edit isn't helpful and doesn't have any plus it will be rejected. And  I didn't said all functions should be created as tags but common ones, that will be useful to categorize a question and that are freaquently used.

Comment: @chsdk The ones I suggested could be seen as common ones, I personally don't see any benefit in that one, however, I was just getting some answers (where Martijn was so nice in pointing me to :)). Even after reading that answer, I don't see the need for yours, unless, you will now go through the full dojo tag and tag every question you find appropriate for the tojson tag

Comment: It's not me who needs to tag all those answers, it's up to the one who posted it to tag it, when it uses it, but tags are useful in the part of indexing answers and for SEO purposes in the first place, so when you search for `toJson` in google you will find those answers easier in the fisrts page of the search.

Comment: I don't think that the question is a duplicate. Even if a tag for a function is ok from the definition given in the duplicate, it is highly doubtful that it is useful. According to that logic we would need a tag for every function of every library. And: Can you be an expert in just one function of a library but not for everything else? Can I be an expert in `c++-abs` but not in `c++-sin`? If not, then how does this categorization make sense?

Comment: @BDL Note that I edited the question after the duplicate link was given, I thought it would be better to edit it, to make clear I also want to have the discussion than to start a new question about it

Comment: @Icepickle: I see. Yes, I completely agree, we should have a discussion about this topic here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purpose of 'method-name' tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260664/purpose-of-method-name-tags)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Although that comes closes, the tag here refers explicitly to api.method, and not to the method name of the function itself. So, I believe it is not a duplicate. I do not know however, how I could edit the question to make it more obvious, as I also don't think that the conclusion would be the same (memberwiseclone could be rather something that more than 1 api / framework can support and has at least a meaningfull name)

Comment: Is your question whether the tag name should include the framework, or whether it should exist at all? If it's the latter, I see no salient difference.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: The proposed duplicate is very close, but not exactly. The major difference I see is that the tags in the duplicate should imho all be burnated because they are ambiguous ([tag:gethashcode] is used for at least 4 languages which impose different restrictions). Second difference is that these tags are about general language functionality while this post is mainly about specific functions of a library.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: If there the question should be closed as a duplicate it would be great if someone could at least ping me. I would then move my answer to the other question for discussion since the answer here has got twice as many votes as the previous (and opposite) answer.

Comment: @BDL If it happens, I will ping you ;)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In my opinion tags shouldn't be used to describe single functions of a library (or a language). The help center states:

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.
>   ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging))

There are several reasons why (in my opinion) tags for single functions aren't useful:

1. In most cases, a programmer will not be an expert in just one function of a language or library. They will at least be familiar with the package that includes this function (and others). Can you, for example, be an expert in [c++-abs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-abs) but not in [c++-sin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-sin)?
2. Having a tag for each single function would let the number of tags explode. Who would be using/monitoring them? A tag that is not actively monitored by users is basically useless. A tag also creates the impression that there is an active community who answers questions in this tag. If this is not the case, asker will be disappointed if their questions don't get answered.
3. A maximum of 5 tags can be added to a question. It is impossible to tag a question with all functions needed to understand the question. In combination with 2., this would lead to more fragmentation of questions instead of categorizing them better.

Comment: I personally agree with your points, especially towards specification tagging, I am just surprised there are no guidelines that define this, other than it is done by users having the necessary reputation

Comment: @Icepickle I guess it was left to common sense, but since common sense is so uncommon today, we should add guidelines.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you posted an answer on the [proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260664/3773011) with the reasoning you [expressed in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360271/should-tags-be-created-for-functions-of-apis#comment537808_360271) that tags for method names without a library should be subject to burnination due to being ambiguous. It'd be nice to be able to upvote such an answer.

Comment: As this vote really seems like a consensus, I am marking it as answered. Just a pity that the tag got approved, though the info and wiki excerpt is well, not really what I would expect from a tag...

Comment: Some method tags could be useful, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/malloc

Comment: @jontro: Feel free to write a competing answer. Imho, malloc is a very good example why such tags shouldn't exist: In 99% the question is not really specific to malloc. At least in the first 30 questions, there is not a single one that really asks about a specific problem with malloc. Most question tagged with it use malloc somewhere in the code but the problem are general memory management, memory access errors, valgrind problems and so on. In addition, the tag contains questions from C, C++, Assembler, Java and Python and question tagged with only [tag:malloc] have almost zero visibility.

Comment: I wouldn't know which experts would follow the malloc tag, since it spans such a wide area of topics. To me it looks like a pure meta-tag.

Comment: @BDL Do you think that consensus was achieved?

Comment: @Rubén: At +40/-1, I'd say yes.