# How could we make [todictionary] less ambiguous?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

There is this [todictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todictionary) tag, with 53 questions.

But the tag is way too ambiguous... It doesn't have a tag wiki nor does it have a tag wiki excerpt.

The original use for this tag (at least I suppose), is for the [C# `toDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary) method. The first question with this tag was with this method.

But there are maybe 30% of the questions are about something else. The other question types are usually about converting [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) (Python library) dataframes to dictionaries...

But I think those should be retagged to just simply [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary)...

Otherwise they get mixed up.

Comment: I agree it looks like it's being misapplied on Python questions. Perhaps some SME could add a tag wiki to indicate that it is about the C# function. Then curators will be more likely to notice it's being misused when they see it.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, that's a possiblity

Comment: Do we need a tag for that one function?

Comment: @MegaIng Maybe simply burninate this tag

Comment: @MegaIng: Usually no; questions about it will contain the literal string "todictionary" which makes it easy to search on. And for people looking for questions to answer, usually they're interested in seeing a more general selection of questions in a language, rather than only being interested in answering questions about a few builtin functions, so it's not really helping potential answerers see the subset of C# questions they want.  (Similar problem to [Creating tags for single assembly instructions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366109) where we decided "no")

Comment: @Peter Well, there is still a `nop` tag with [57 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nop). But that's a *very* special assembly instruction, I guess. :-)

Comment: ... And quite a few of those 57 are about nopCommerce or other non-assembler stuffs.

Comment: @AdrianMole: There's also a `[mov]` tag with [283 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mov), unfortunately.  It's one of the silliest tags because "being an expert" in it just means that you know it copies data on whatever ISA we happen to be talking about.  Many ISAs have an insn with that mnemonic, and questions about it are usually about addressing modes (which have their own tag), or about operand-sizes and zero- / sign-extension.

Comment: Seems like this has been done, there are no questions left.  Mark as [`[status-completed]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), or is there some way to blacklist the tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to have been solved.

The tag has been burninated.

Now there are 0 questions tagged [todictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todictionary)!

Hooray, !!! Finally [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) !!!

Answer (score 77):

#### Just remove it.

The tag provides zero value for C#. The `ToDictionary` method is nothing special, does not act special, has no special compiler support that would set it apart from any other method in the .NET Framework (or .NET Core or .NET 5 or 6 or any other).

We do not need one tag per method.

The same goes for the `IDictionary` tag that I saw when looking at the questions by the way.

While `IEnumerable` is a very special interface that does special things and has special compiler support, therefor deserving a tag, `IDictionary`, `Dictionary`, `ToDictionary` do not.

One could argue that `dictionary` is not C# specific and could be a synonym to some other lookup table tag, the tag in question here should just be nuked. It's pointless noise.

I cannot speak for other languages, but I would suspect it's the same there. If it's relevant for *other* languages, it should be clearly marked as such and then removed from all C# questions.

Comment: I agree 100% It should die

Comment: If it had been a worthwhile tag, somebody would have written a wiki for it by now. And if removing it is a mistake, then it'll pop up again at some point.

Comment: Can any SMEs pick out any of the (current) 53 questions where simply removing the tag would cause harm? If not, let's just remove them all and burn, burn, burn the tag. But I'll wait for some kind of "approval" before I start editing-out the tags.

Comment: @einpoklum Even if removing it is not a mistake, it will probably pop up again at some point :)

Comment: @chepner that hasn't happened with [internet], so lets see.

Comment: Agree, definitely no need in the C# space for the todictionary tag.

Comment: I removed it from all .NET questions, sometimes replacing it with more appropriate tags. I guess somebody else is doing the same for the non-NET questions, the number is shrinking :)

Comment: Agree it should be removed.  That being said, `ToDictionary()` lives in the `System.Linq` namespace, so c# questions about `ToDictionary()` can be tagged with [tag:linq] which is more than sufficient I think.  Also: [`[c#] -[todictionary] todictionary`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+-[todictionary]+todictionary) returns 7,869 questions so the tag isn't even helping to find questions about `ToDictionary()`.