# Can we please unlist [tolist]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

When working on [How could we make [todictionary] less ambiguous?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415038/how-could-we-make-todictionary-less-ambiguous?cb=1) I came across questions with the [tolist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tolist) tag.

It has all the same problems as the [todictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todictionary) tag:

No tag wiki, no description, a function name in [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) that is nothing special. It doesn't do anything differently than all the other functions in the .NET framework. Since it literally takes no parameters and has no side effects, I don't see how one can ever be an expert in `.ToList()` other than typing it faster than others.

I will self-answer this, but please add your own answers if I overlooked anything. Maybe it's really important and valuable in other languages and just needs a tag wiki to make sure it's used for only those.

Comment: Note that there are about twice as many questions with [tag:tolist] compared to [tag:todictionary]. Also, it's not as limited as the other one to C# and pandas. terraform, flutter and probably a few other usage contexts are also there. Someone who knows about those should probably look at them and see if a tag like this might be useful there.

Comment: @MegaIng a tag for a single function is never useful, and just serve to reinforce the idea that tags are hashtags instead of topics.

Comment: @MegaIng I have no experience in pandas and terraform, but with flutter/dart it's the same as with C#. Yes, it exists. It isn't special in any way.

Comment: Java also has `Collectors.toList()` but it's similarly not really special and unlikely to really require a tag for itself. I think that in general, tags for functions/methods/properties are unneeded. *Maybe* for some but that should be very rare. Most of the times I find that tagging the function/method/property is an XY problem.

Comment: @Braiam Yes of course. If it's just a non special function the tag can just be removed. I don't know whether or not that is true for all those other topics as well. The question therefore is if nvoigt's answer applies to all topics that this tag is used in.

Comment: "[tolist] or not [tolist]"

Comment: @nvoigt want to start one for `[toarray]`?

Comment: cleaned up within .net, c# and vb.net

Comment: To me it seems like a waste of time removing these kinds of tags. What problems exactly are they causing which merit their removal? Also, what's with the jokey names like "unlist [tolist]"?

Comment: @trinalbadger587 [last question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295583/792066). Also, it's not about what causes harm, is about what value it provides. The only way that a high quality library is achieved is by setting a high bar. Mediocre content (or tags) can't be allowed.

Answer (score 37):

#### Just remove it.

The tag provides zero value for [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). The `ToList` method is nothing special, does not act special, has no special compiler support that would set it apart from any other method in the .NET Framework (or .NET Core or .NET 5 or 6 or any other).

We do not need one tag per method.

While IEnumerable is a very special interface that does special things and has special compiler support, therefore deserving a tag, IList and ToList do not.

I cannot speak for other languages, but I would suspect it's the same there. If it's relevant for other languages, it should be clearly marked as such and then removed from all C# questions.

---

Since it came up: the same goes for the [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) or more precisely [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart) function of the same name.

Comment: [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList%28%29).

Comment: I'm not arguing against removing the tag, but in .NET, `.ToList` is a bit special.  It's the idiomatic way to materialize a collection (when using LINQ-based technologies, the result you get is typed as an `IEnumerable<T>` (i.e., a collection of `T`), but the actual items in the collection are not gathered into a real collection until the collection is enumerated (for example in a `foreach` statement or a `.ToList` call).  I'm only saying the `.ToList` method is not _"nothing special"_.  It's something that takes newbies a bit by surprise

Comment: Well, as I said in my answer, the *special* case is `IEnumerable<>` that behaves different from other interfaces. ToList materializes IEnumerables, but so does any other method that enumerates the IEnumerable. So if anything takes newbies by surprise, it's IEnumerable.

Comment: @Flydog57, it is IEnumerable which is special. deferred execution surprises many, not only newbies. ToList works just as well with array . but `.ToList().ForEach()` combo is a special evil.

Comment: It may be something that takes newbies by surprise, but unless the newbies know that the ToList in their code (or perhaps more often, the lack of it?) is what's causing a problem, then they won't know to use the tag anyway.

Comment: @Flydog57 Just because c# `IQueryable<T>.ToList()` is a shortcut to iterate over and therefore realise the results of an expression, it is ambiguous to tag a related question with [ToList], tagging with `expression` or `Linq` or `Linq-to-XXXX` variants is more useful. `.ToList()` is the least significant component to debugging a linq expression (other than a common point where execution occurs) it is not the only command that can be used to evaluate the expression which further adds to the ambiguity.

Comment: For c# and .net I think the [tag:linq] tag is sufficient here also, as well as a language and/or framework tag if one is missing (e.g. [How to convert LINQ query result to List?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10333619/3744182).)

Comment: Why not merge it into [list]?

Comment: @Laurel why should we? Why shouldn't we just delete it?

Comment: @Braiam It only takes a minute to merge it (or make a synonym) with none of the drawbacks of manual editing (time consuming, bumps). Plus, not all questions there have the list tag.

Comment: @Laurel None of those "drawbacks" seems drawbacks to me, meanwhile your solution is full of the same drawbacks this solution fixes, merging or synonimizing will keep a bad tag on questions.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the fact that the C# `ToList()` function really isn't that hard to use and doesn't merit its own tag, I would like to add that this is actually rather ambiguous. It's used for numerous different languages, including C#, VB.NET, Python, Java, and even occasionally C++, with no one use being more "correct" than any of the other uses. The odds of someone actually knowing about all of those things seems quite low, and it's really not identifying a unique programming topic.

This tag should be removed.